# How random is random.shuffle()?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

How random is the `random.shuffle()` w/o seed?

Inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxJubaijQbI), how random should the `random.shuffle()` be expected (without a seed). In practice, is it a good idea to call this function several times to achieve higher level of randomness, or one call is enough?

Comment: `random.shuffle()` *is* seeded -- Python just takes care of the seeding boilerplate for you. The only time you would do anything different is for reproducibility, not for better randomness. Calling it several times before using it would be pointless.

Comment: @ John Coleman , I know, thanks! I actually wanted to make the question more specific, that is, I wonder if one `shuffle()` is enough to achieve randomness (as random as it gets in the pseudorandom environment)

Comment: Under the hood it doubtless does a Fisher-Yates shuffle (or variation thereof). Shuffling more than once won't increase the randomness. You could run some statistical tests if you are skeptical.

Comment: That's not how "randomness" works. You're not shuffling cards by hand, in which case shuffling more than once *is* recommended. This shuffle depends on the quality of the (pseudo) random number generator; if it is decent, which it hopefully is, then one shuffle is very random already.

Comment: If you look at the [Diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) (which the Mersenne Twister, Python's PRNG, does well on) one of them involves how well the random number generator does in generating random permutations.

Comment: @ John Coleman  and @ deceze , unfortunately I'm not to good at understanding something that cannot be checked directly against (in this particular case, the "randomness"), which is why I asked this question. Aren't , in general, more manipulations (say, `x` manipulations vs `1000*x` manipulatiosn against the list would achieve higher level of randomness? In my particular case, I deal with array of len approx. 1.5mil elements...

Comment: Read about the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). There is no reason to do it more than once. If it worked by doing something like `n` random pairwise swaps, then doing it more than once would make sense, but that isn't how it works.

Comment: Oh ok. Gotcha. Is there any sort of reference I can read through that confirms that Python's `random.shuffle()` complies with Diehard tests and uses  Fisher-Yates Shuffle ? Cheers

Comment: Python is open-source and well-documented, and the Mersenne Twister has its own Wikipedia page (with many references to explore). You should be able to find the references you seek, as well as the [actual source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/random.py#L293) if you are interested.

Comment: Cheers John, will do once I finish my burning project. If I may ask, what were you referencing `Mersenne Twister ` in regards to? :)

Comment: The Mersenne Twister is what Python uses as its random number generator